# Difference among | and ; and &

Tags: linux, shell

I have seen `|` and `;` and `&` to be used to batch together multiple commands on Linux shell. What are the differences among them?

Thanks.

Comment: `|` pipes things, `&` backgrounds things (or does an AND if doubled) and I've never seen `,` :P

Comment: Might as well also ask about `;`

Comment: I meant to say ; not , . I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'|'` is called the pipe symbol, it is used to take the output from one command and "pipe" it to another one.

e.g.,

```
  ls | wc -l
```

takes the output of the `ls` command and provides it to the `wc -l` command which counts the number of lines. It is quite common to have several pipes in a row output at various stages.

Here's a page that talks about [pipes](http://www.december.com/unix/tutor/pipesfilters.html).

The `'&'` is used to put a command in the background so that it can run, while you are returned to the command prompt and can continue to issue other commands.

This [page](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34623-unixlinux-background-processing/) has a short example of a pipe and the amperstand to put something in the background. This page talks about [managing background commands](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/). Finally, under `sh`/`bash` (and possibly shells other than `csh`/`tcsh`) `'&'` can be used to [redirect stdout and stderr](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) as @cdarke reminds us in a helpful comment below.

Any decent Linux/Unix tutorial would give you more information on these two.

I haven't seen the `,` used with commands, though `;` can be used to [group several commands](http://www.december.com/unix/demo/group.html).

Also see @Bruno comment below for more information about using `&&` to chain commands in bash.

Comment: The `,` is the "comma-operator", as used in many languages.  In a shell its typical use would be `(( x=y*2,x++,z=y/2 ))`.  It is also used in counting `for` loops (as in C/Java/Perl/PHP, etc.).  Each command is executed left-to-right, the result of the whole statement is the result of the rightmost.

Comment: & (a.k.a. "Donald Duck") is not only used to background jobs, it is also used to indicate redirection to a file descriptor, as in `ls -l 2>&1` and `exec 2>&3`.

Comment: @cdarke Good point .. I'll add a line about this to my answer, thanks for reminding me about this.

Comment: Assuming bash, you also get `&&` to chain commands, where the execution of a command will depend on the return value of the previous one (true is 0, here). This can be used similarly to `;`, except that `;` will execute the next command anyway. See: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html

Comment: @Bruno interesting, I think I've come across the `&&` once or twice before (I'm more of a tcsh user). I'll add a note to my answer pointing to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
&
```

Puts a task in the background.

```
|
```

Pushes the std out of the previous command onto the std in of the next one.

```
,
```

I've never seen before.  Where have you seen it?